# Laptop internal microphone not working, after plugging HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, microphone

My laptop internal microphone does not work anymore, after plugging HDMI for the first time.

I just bought a new Dell Precision 5760, shipped with Ubuntu 20.04.  I installed a few things, including Zoom, and I actually made calls successfully.

But now the microphone does not work anymore.  If I open Ubuntu settings and go to the "Sound" panel, the "Input" meter does not react to sound as it did before.

The only thing I made between the mic working and not working, was to plug my laptop to an external screen, using HDMI (for the very first time, this is a brand new laptop.)

I have no idea how to gather more information about this.  Any idea?

[image: system settings, sound panel]

[EDIT]

In `pavucontrol`, the profile of `sof-soundwire` is set to the only available choice: `Play HiFi quality Music` (the only other choice available is `Off`):

[image]

As for the input device, the only one available is selected, and looks like the internal mic to me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- install pavucontrol (pulse audio volume control)
- In pavucontrol  **configuration** tab, check  "profile" is not set to HDMI but to analog. Check  **input tab** for correct input if available.

Comment: Thank you!  I had already checked that, and all looks OK to me.  I've edited my question with more info from pavucontrol.  I don't know how to find any more relevant info :-(